# Decoding JSON to give me a certain variable in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, decode

I'm using Python 2.7, and what I'm trying to do is this:
I have the following JSON String.

http://www.ows.newegg.com/Products.egg/N82E16822148992

In this string, there are multiple values called `FinalPrice`. I'm trying to get the `MAIN FinalPrice` for the item in question (the item here is `#N82E16822148992`). The `main FinalPrice` would be the one that refers to the main item on the page. The corresponding page for this JSON page is `http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148992`.

So, would there be any way to grab the `FinalPrice` I need out of usually around 10 `FinalPrices` (I say usually because I've only tested the number of `FinalPrices` with 3 links and they're all ten)? I thought maybe I could find a way by using the product name to find the location of the final price, but there's always **page-specific characters** between the name of the product and the `FinalPrice`.

What can I do about this?

P.S Here's what I've tried:
I've looked at Python.org's JSON documentation, but it didn't help me much with finding the specific FinalPrice (or maybe I was just looking at it wrong?)
I've tried making the whole JSON page a string, and using some string manipulation (s.find, s[a:b]) to get the FinalPrice I need, but I couldn't find a way to get any FinalPrice besides the first one.
I've searched on Google and Stack Overflow for a proper answer to this.

That's about all I've done so far.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Can we dispense with that link? The OP would be better served with a request to add some more information, *perhaps* with a friendly pointer to that site. The URL to that site could be removed and the OP would be none the wiser.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I would normally write more explaining why it is important to post what one has tried. However, I have seen too many such questions today, already. Also, that webpage does a pretty good job explaining this, reading which, would take the pressure off of me to provide such an explanation. I really did not intend to be rude in my comment, and apologize if that's how it came across.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I feel your pain, but every new OP does not. Use [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) and write great answers that are then available to you at a click away.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add what I tried. I understand how it would've been seen as really vague and hard to help with.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you so much for that link. It seems to be made with the distilled essence of pure awesome. I've never seen it before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main top-level data structure of the JSON data you linked has only *one* `FinalPrice` key, so it should be trivial to get this information:

```
>>> import urllib2, json
>>> data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ows.newegg.com/Products.egg/N82E16822148992'))
>>> print data[u'FinalPrice']
$79.99
```

You can use the [`pprint.pprint` function](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) to get a quick feel of the data structure:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data)
{u'AddToCartButtonText': u'Add to Cart',
 u'AddToCartButtonType': u'AD',
 u'AverageRating': 0,
 u'BrandInfo': None,
 u'CanAddToCart': False,
 u'ComboCount': 5,
 u'CoremetricsInfo': {u'Brand': u'Seagate',
                      u'CategoryID': u'IPS380',
                      u'PageID': u'PRODUCT: NBHD 320G|ST ST320LT014 7K SATA3G %_22-148-992 (22-148-992)',
                      u'ProductName': u'NBHD 320G|ST ST320LT014 7K SATA3G %_22-148-992'},
 u'Discount': u'You Save: $10.00',
 u'ETA': u'/Date(-62135568000000)/',
 u'EmailFriendImageInfo': {u'FullPath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S35$',
                           u'ItemNumber': None,
                           u'PathSize100': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S100$',
                           u'PathSize125': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S125$',
                           u'PathSize180': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S180$',
                           u'PathSize300': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S300$',
                           u'PathSize35': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S35$',
                           u'PathSize60': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S60$',
                           u'PathSize640': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S640$',
                           u'SmallImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S125$',
                           u'ThumbnailImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S60$',
                           u'Title': None},
 u'EnergyStarText': None,
 u'FinalPrice': u'$79.99',
 u'FreeShippingFlag': True,
 u'HasMappingPrice': False,
 u'Image': {u'FullPath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S180$',
            u'ItemNumber': None,
            u'PathSize100': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S100$',
            u'PathSize125': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S125$',
            u'PathSize180': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S180$',
            u'PathSize300': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S300$',
            u'PathSize35': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S35$',
            u'PathSize60': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S60$',
            u'PathSize640': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S640$',
            u'SmallImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S100$',
            u'ThumbnailImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S60$',
            u'Title': None},
 u'InstantSaving': 0,
 u'Instock': True,
 u'InstockForCombo': False,
 u'IronEggDescription': None,
 u'IsActivated': True,
 u'IsCellPhoneItem': False,
 u'IsComboBundle': False,
 u'IsFeaturedItem': False,
 u'IsHot': False,
 u'IsInPMCC': False,
 u'IsPreLaunch': False,
 u'IsShellShockerItem': False,
 u'IsShipByNewegg': True,
 u'IsShowEnergyStarSection': False,
 u'IsShowSoldOutText': False,
 u'ItemGroupID': 0,
 u'ItemMapPriceMarkType': 0,
 u'ItemNumber': u'22-148-992',
 u'ItemOwnerType': 0,
 u'LimitQuantity': -1,
 u'MailInRebateInfo': None,
 u'MailInRebateText': None,
 u'MappingFinalPrice': None,
 u'Model': u'ST320LT014',
 u'NeweggItemNumber': None,
 u'NumberOfReviews': 0,
 u'OriginalPrice': u'$89.99',
 u'ParentItem': None,
 u'ProductProperties': None,
 u'ProductStockType': 0,
 u'PromotionInfo': None,
 u'PromotionText': u'',
 u'ReturnPolicyInfo': {u'HtmlContent': None,
                       u'ID': u'44',
                       u'Name': u'Standard Return Policy'},
 u'ReviewSummary': {u'Rating': 0, u'TotalReviews': u'[]'},
 u'SellerId': None,
 u'SellerItemPropertyList': None,
 u'SellerName': None,
 u'ShipByNewegg': 0,
 u'ShippingInfo': {u'NormalShippingText': u'Free Shipping*',
                   u'RestrictedShippingText': u' Additional fees may apply for shipments to APO/FPO, AK, HI and PR.',
                   u'RestrictedShippingTitle': u'Shipping Restrictions',
                   u'SpecialShippingText': u' Additional fees may apply for shipments to APO/FPO, AK, HI and PR.'},
 u'ShippingPromotionInfo': None,
 u'ShoppingInsight': {u'Description': u'See what other informed Newegg customers purchased after viewing this product',
                      u'PromotionItems': [{u'AfterRebate': None,
                                           u'FinalPrice': u'$149.99',
                                           u'Instock': True,
                                           u'IsCurrentItem': False,
                                           u'IsFreeShipping': True,
                                           u'IsShowOriginalPrice': False,
                                           u'ItemBrand': {u'BrandId': 1305,
                                                          u'BrandImage': u'http://images10.newegg.com/brandimage/Brand1305.gif',
                                                          u'Code': 0,
                                                          u'Description': u'Seagate',
                                                          u'HasManfactoryLogo': True,
                                                          u'ManufactoryWeb': u'http://www.seagate.com',
                                                          u'WebSiteURL': None},
                                           u'ItemImage': {u'FullPath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-591-TS?$S180W$',
                                                          u'ItemNumber': None,
                                                          u'PathSize100': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-591-TS?$S100$',
                                                          u'PathSize125': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-591-TS?$S125W$',
                                                          u'PathSize180': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-591-TS?$S180W$',
                                                          u'PathSize300': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-591-TS?$S300W$',
                                                          u'PathSize35': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-591-TS?$S35$',
                                                          u'PathSize60': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-591-TS?$S60$',
                                                          u'PathSize640': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-591-TS?$S640W$',
                                                          u'SmallImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-591-TS?$S125W$',
                                                          u'ThumbnailImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-591-TS?$S60$',
                                                          u'Title': None},
                                           u'ItemMapPriceMarkType': 0,
                                           u'ItemNumber': u'22-148-591',
                                           u'MappingFinalPrice': None,
                                           u'OriginalPrice': u'$149.99',
                                           u'Percentage': u'22',
                                           u'ReviewSummary': {u'Rating': 4,
                                                              u'TotalReviews': u'[829]'},
                                           u'Title': u'Seagate Momentus XT ST95005620AS 500GB 7200 RPM 32MB Cache 2.5" SATA 3.0Gb/s with NCQ Solid State Hybrid Drive -Bare Drive'},
                                          {u'AfterRebate': None,
                                           u'FinalPrice': u'$79.99',
                                           u'Instock': True,
                                           u'IsCurrentItem': True,
                                           u'IsFreeShipping': True,
                                           u'IsShowOriginalPrice': True,
                                           u'ItemBrand': {u'BrandId': 1305,
                                                          u'BrandImage': u'http://images10.newegg.com/brandimage/Brand1305.gif',
                                                          u'Code': 0,
                                                          u'Description': u'Seagate',
                                                          u'HasManfactoryLogo': True,
                                                          u'ManufactoryWeb': u'http://www.seagate.com',
                                                          u'WebSiteURL': None},
                                           u'ItemImage': {u'FullPath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S180$',
                                                          u'ItemNumber': None,
                                                          u'PathSize100': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S100$',
                                                          u'PathSize125': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S125$',
                                                          u'PathSize180': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S180$',
                                                          u'PathSize300': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S300$',
                                                          u'PathSize35': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S35$',
                                                          u'PathSize60': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S60$',
                                                          u'PathSize640': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S640$',
                                                          u'SmallImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S125$',
                                                          u'ThumbnailImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-TS?$S60$',
                                                          u'Title': None},
                                           u'ItemMapPriceMarkType': 0,
                                           u'ItemNumber': u'22-148-992',
                                           u'MappingFinalPrice': None,
                                           u'OriginalPrice': u'$89.99',
                                           u'Percentage': u'16',
                                           u'ReviewSummary': {u'Rating': 0,
                                                              u'TotalReviews': u'[]'},
                                           u'Title': u'Seagate Momentus Thin ST320LT014 320GB 7200 RPM 16MB Cache 2.5" SATA 3.0Gb/s Internal Notebook Hard Drive -Bare Drive'},
                                          {u'AfterRebate': None,
                                           u'FinalPrice': u'$69.99',
                                           u'Instock': True,
                                           u'IsCurrentItem': False,
                                           u'IsFreeShipping': False,
                                           u'IsShowOriginalPrice': True,
                                           u'ItemBrand': {u'BrandId': 1306,
                                                          u'BrandImage': u'http://images10.newegg.com/brandimage/Brand1306.gif',
                                                          u'Code': 0,
                                                          u'Description': u'Western Digital',
                                                          u'HasManfactoryLogo': True,
                                                          u'ManufactoryWeb': u'http://www.wdc.com/en/',
                                                          u'WebSiteURL': None},
                                           u'ItemImage': {u'FullPath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-136-280-TS?$S180W$',
                                                          u'ItemNumber': None,
                                                          u'PathSize100': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-136-280-TS?$S100$',
                                                          u'PathSize125': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-136-280-TS?$S125W$',
                                                          u'PathSize180': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-136-280-TS?$S180W$',
                                                          u'PathSize300': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-136-280-TS?$S300W$',
                                                          u'PathSize35': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-136-280-TS?$S35$',
                                                          u'PathSize60': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-136-280-TS?$S60$',
                                                          u'PathSize640': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-136-280-TS?$S640W$',
                                                          u'SmallImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-136-280-TS?$S125W$',
                                                          u'ThumbnailImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-136-280-TS?$S60$',
                                                          u'Title': None},
                                           u'ItemMapPriceMarkType': 0,
                                           u'ItemNumber': u'22-136-280',
                                           u'MappingFinalPrice': None,
                                           u'OriginalPrice': u'$89.99',
                                           u'Percentage': u'16',
                                           u'ReviewSummary': {u'Rating': 5,
                                                              u'TotalReviews': u'[1,299]'},
                                           u'Title': u'Western Digital Scorpio Black WD3200BEKT 320GB 7200 RPM 16MB Cache 2.5" SATA 3.0Gb/s Internal Notebook Hard Drive -Bare Drive'},
                                          {u'AfterRebate': None,
                                           u'FinalPrice': u'$59.99',
                                           u'Instock': True,
                                           u'IsCurrentItem': False,
                                           u'IsFreeShipping': True,
                                           u'IsShowOriginalPrice': True,
                                           u'ItemBrand': {u'BrandId': 1305,
                                                          u'BrandImage': u'http://images10.newegg.com/brandimage/Brand1305.gif',
                                                          u'Code': 0,
                                                          u'Description': u'Seagate',
                                                          u'HasManfactoryLogo': True,
                                                          u'ManufactoryWeb': u'http://www.seagate.com',
                                                          u'WebSiteURL': None},
                                           u'ItemImage': {u'FullPath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-906-TS?$S180$',
                                                          u'ItemNumber': None,
                                                          u'PathSize100': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-906-TS?$S100$',
                                                          u'PathSize125': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-906-TS?$S125$',
                                                          u'PathSize180': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-906-TS?$S180$',
                                                          u'PathSize300': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-906-TS?$S300$',
                                                          u'PathSize35': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-906-TS?$S35$',
                                                          u'PathSize60': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-906-TS?$S60$',
                                                          u'PathSize640': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-906-TS?$S640$',
                                                          u'SmallImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-906-TS?$S125$',
                                                          u'ThumbnailImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-906-TS?$S60$',
                                                          u'Title': None},
                                           u'ItemMapPriceMarkType': 0,
                                           u'ItemNumber': u'22-148-906',
                                           u'MappingFinalPrice': None,
                                           u'OriginalPrice': u'$69.99',
                                           u'Percentage': u'11',
                                           u'ReviewSummary': {u'Rating': 5,
                                                              u'TotalReviews': u'[1]'},
                                           u'Title': u'Seagate Momentus Thin ST250LT003 250GB 5400 RPM 16MB Cache 2.5" SATA 3.0Gb/s Internal Notebook Hard Drive -Bare Drive'}]},
 u'ShowOriginalPrice': True,
 u'StaticText': None,
 u'StrAddItem': None,
 u'StrAlt': None,
 u'StrCartImg': None,
 u'SubCategoryId': 380,
 u'SubCategoryName': u'Laptop Hard Drives',
 u'Title': u'Seagate Momentus Thin ST320LT014 320GB 7200 RPM 16MB Cache 2.5" SATA 3.0Gb/s Internal Notebook Hard Drive -Bare Drive',
 u'UnitPrice': 0,
 u'Warnings': None,
 u'WarrantyInfo': None,
 u'XmlSpec': None,
 u'imageGallery': [{u'FullPath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z01?$S640$',
                    u'ItemNumber': None,
                    u'PathSize100': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z01?$S100$',
                    u'PathSize125': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z01?$S125$',
                    u'PathSize180': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z01?$S180$',
                    u'PathSize300': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z01?$S300$',
                    u'PathSize35': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z01?$S35$',
                    u'PathSize60': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z01?$S60$',
                    u'PathSize640': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z01?$S640$',
                    u'SmallImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z01?$S100$',
                    u'ThumbnailImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z01?$S60$',
                    u'Title': None},
                   {u'FullPath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z02?$S640$',
                    u'ItemNumber': None,
                    u'PathSize100': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z02?$S100$',
                    u'PathSize125': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z02?$S125$',
                    u'PathSize180': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z02?$S180$',
                    u'PathSize300': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z02?$S300$',
                    u'PathSize35': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z02?$S35$',
                    u'PathSize60': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z02?$S60$',
                    u'PathSize640': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z02?$S640$',
                    u'SmallImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z02?$S100$',
                    u'ThumbnailImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z02?$S60$',
                    u'Title': None},
                   {u'FullPath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z03?$S640$',
                    u'ItemNumber': None,
                    u'PathSize100': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z03?$S100$',
                    u'PathSize125': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z03?$S125$',
                    u'PathSize180': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z03?$S180$',
                    u'PathSize300': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z03?$S300$',
                    u'PathSize35': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z03?$S35$',
                    u'PathSize60': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z03?$S60$',
                    u'PathSize640': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z03?$S640$',
                    u'SmallImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z03?$S100$',
                    u'ThumbnailImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z03?$S60$',
                    u'Title': None},
                   {u'FullPath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z04?$S640$',
                    u'ItemNumber': None,
                    u'PathSize100': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z04?$S100$',
                    u'PathSize125': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z04?$S125$',
                    u'PathSize180': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z04?$S180$',
                    u'PathSize300': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z04?$S300$',
                    u'PathSize35': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z04?$S35$',
                    u'PathSize60': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z04?$S60$',
                    u'PathSize640': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z04?$S640$',
                    u'SmallImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z04?$S100$',
                    u'ThumbnailImagePath': u'http://images17.newegg.com/is/image/newegg/22-148-992-Z04?$S60$',
                    u'Title': None}]}
```

You can then see that the other `FinalPrice` entries are part of the `ShoppingInsight` -> `PromotionItems` structure, which is a list:

```
>>> print data[u'ShoppingInsight'][u'PromotionItems'][0][u'FinalPrice']
$149.99
>>> print data[u'ShoppingInsight'][u'PromotionItems'][0][u'Title']
Seagate Momentus XT ST95005620AS 500GB 7200 RPM 32MB Cache 2.5" SATA 3.0Gb/s with NCQ Solid State Hybrid Drive -Bare Drive
```

Comment: Thanks! Even with my vague post and terrible question, this helped a LOT.

Answer (score 2):

Use the json parser. For example, if I save the web page of data you provided to a file called json_data then I can do this...

```
  import json
  json_data=open('json_data')

  data = json.load(json_data)
  print(data["FinalPrice"])
  json_data.close()
```

Or if you already have the data in a variable just use the json.load on that variable.